# Symfony 2.3.* authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication, vagrant, symfony-2.3

After testing clean install of `Symfony` 2.3 inside vagrant with `Ubuntu 12.04.4` and `14.04` like this:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition login_not_working 2.3.*
```

update vendors:

```
composer install
```

edit app_dev.php like this, on first line after `<?php` for permissions:

```
umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

go to:

```
http://vagrant.dev/app_dev.php/
```

i click nice green button with `RUN THE DEMO` text and try to login with `user/userpass` or `admin/adminpass`. Symfony redirects me to:

```
http://vagrant.dev/app_dev.php/
```

and in the profiler i see very impressive message `You are not authenticated.` and with the extremly impressive red button too :D

This is just for testing and in actual application happens the same thing but on different setup... there i am using `SonataUserBundle` that extends `FOSUserBundle`...but it behaves the same...

I cleared cookies over, at least, 3 different browsers, clean cache with console and manually,...yada yada...

It smells like something with my vagrant box setup with/or/and a little flavor of permissions or maybe even sessions or ... boy is this kinky or what?

**EDIT:**

So, i uploaded both apps (clean test and my actual app with `SonataUserBundle`) to my VPS and both are workin' fine. Still, on few of my vagrant boxes authentication is not working?

And `app/check.php` output:

```
$ php app/check.php

 OK       PHP version must be at least 5.3.3 (5.5.12-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 installed)
 OK       PHP version must not be 5.3.16 as Symfony wont work properly with it
 OK       Vendor libraries must be installed
 OK       app/cache/ directory must be writable
 OK       app/logs/ directory must be writable
 OK       date.timezone setting must be set
 OK       Configured default timezone "Europe/Berlin" must be supported by your installation of PHP
 OK       json_encode() must be available
 OK       session_start() must be available
 OK       ctype_alpha() must be available
 OK       token_get_all() must be available
 OK       simplexml_import_dom() must be available
 OK       detect_unicode must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       xdebug.show_exception_trace must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       xdebug.scream must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       PCRE extension must be available

** Optional recommendations **

 OK       xdebug.max_nesting_level should be above 100 in php.ini
 OK       Requirements file should be up-to-date
 OK       You should use at least PHP 5.3.4 due to PHP bug #52083 in earlier versions
 OK       When using annotations you should have at least PHP 5.3.8 due to PHP bug #55156
 OK       You should not use PHP 5.4.0 due to the PHP bug #61453
 OK       When using the logout handler from the Symfony Security Component, you should have at least PHP 5.4.11 due to PHP bug #63379 (as a workaround, you can also set invalidate_session to false in the security logout handler configuration)
 OK       You should use PHP 5.3.18+ or PHP 5.4.8+ to always get nice error messages for fatal errors in the development environment due to PHP bug #61767/#60909
 OK       PCRE extension should be at least version 8.0 (8.12 installed)
 OK       PHP-XML module should be installed
 OK       mb_strlen() should be available
 OK       iconv() should be available
 OK       utf8_decode() should be available
 OK       posix_isatty() should be available
 OK       intl extension should be available
 OK       intl extension should be correctly configured
 OK       intl ICU version should be at least 4+
 OK       a PHP accelerator should be installed
 OK       short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       magic_quotes_gpc should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       register_globals should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       session.auto_start should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       PDO should be installed
 OK       PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: mysql, sqlite)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, anyway, to answer my own question (kind of) and for the audience...thank you i'm fine... ;)

I configured Symfony to store sessions in memcached and that seems to resolve the problem (kind of). I'll test this on another machine/vagrant to confirm this :D

This "(kinf of)" is whole another story, but i'll leave that for another time :D

**EDIT**

I tested this on 2 more vagrant boxes and storing sessions to memcached resolve it :)